# jquery ui draggable element appears behind other elements?

Tags: jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, draggable, jquery-draggable

I am using jquery ui draggable, and eventually droppable to make it possible to reorder pictures into different boxes.

When I drag a picture out of the box it appears under all the other elements once it leaves its direct container.

While googling I was able to found to add:

```
   helper: 'clone',
   appendTo: "body"
```

This makes it so what is being dragged appears on top of all elements, but it leaves the original copy still in the box and I do not want that.

Is there a way I can make the element stay on top of everything when being dragged? I have tried a high z-index to no avail.

Here is a jsfiddle that shows the first draggle element behind behind the second. it is not an issue the other way around.
i am not able to change the position relative on the containing divs without breaking a lot of other things.

http://jsfiddle.net/cBWhX/6/

Comment: Can you include a jsFiddle?

Comment: @bobthyasian http://jsfiddle.net/cBWhX/6/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found a few issues with your code, I think I've worked them out and got it working.

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/cBWhX/7/)**

First fix your HTML:

```
<div id="container1" style="background-color:red;padding:20px">
    <div class="draggableContainer">
        <div class="draggable" style="background-color:blue;width:200px;height:200px;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="draggableContainer">
        <div class="draggable" style="background-color:yellow;width:200px;height:200px;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="draggableContainer"></div>
</div>
```

Next You'll probably want to use the [stack option](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-stack):

```
$('.draggable').draggable({
    revert: "invalid",
    snap: ".draggableContainer",
    stack: ".draggable"
});

$('.draggableContainer').droppable()
```

From the [API documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-stack):

> **Stack**
>   Controls the z-index of the set of elements that match the selector, always brings the currently dragged item to the front.

Answer (score 0):

Though there is an option - '**stack**' existing while initiating draggables, but it is not working properly, So I have wrote a small library dragToFront playing with z-index. Following is the plunkr link

https://embed.plnkr.co/mJqkxSJhf1Umg7r2oLQN/

Answer (score 0):

Stack wasn't working for me either. I was able to correct the z-index issue by using the `appendTo` property.

```
function setupDraggableFields($elements) {
    $elements.draggable({
        helper: "clone",
        handle: ".field-sort-handle",
        appendTo: ".section-container"
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For what its worth you can also use a function in `helper:`.

Ex:

```
helper: function() {
    var dragEl = $("<div></div>").append($(this).data('name'));
    return dragEl
},
```

With this you could set new z values.